# How to avoid layout reloading?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm building an MVC application and I've noticed when I navigate through the app the layout gets reloaded along with my content.

**I know this is default and expected behavior.**

I'd really like to avoid reloading the layout, any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have minimum two abilities:

- Use Ajax helper (`@Ajax.ActionLink`)

  - [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586327/how-to-use-ajax-actionlink)
  - [Link 2](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/ajax-actionlink-and-html-actionlink-in-mvc/)
- Use javascript/jquery

  - [Link 1](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Main idea is load `PartialView` with ajax requests and insert/replace content in DOM.

Comment: I feared that, I've done [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903078/how-to-update-my-content-async-with-javascript/11903079#11903079) function to update content async. I think I don't have many choices here. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @Esteban If you want only content, without html-markup, then look at client templating, for example this [JsRender: Demos](http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/demos/demos.html). Server return json and then you fill your page.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to instruct it to not reload the layout

The Layout gets rendered at the backend as soon as you request the url it returns a view that it redered with the layout .

However using ajax to load your views is bad for SEO you can do some workarounds.
Or should i say SEO is stupid and someone should Fix that shit.

I posted a link to show you how the crawlers act when you have a ajax website

http://moz.com/blog/how-to-allow-google-to-crawl-ajax-content

There are some great frameworks out there like Backbone , angularjs,knockout that makes it simple to accomplish what you wanto do.